# Multiple Azure Virtual Machines on same Cloud Service

Tags: php, azure, phpmyadmin, virtual-machine

I have a cloud service on `Azure` and on that cloud service, I have 2 `VMs`. And I have `apache`, `php`, `mysql`, `phpmyadmin` installed on both. Both the VMs lie on the same availability set as well.

If my cloud service `dns` is `hello.cloudapp.net` and I access phpmyadmin by going to `hello.cloudapp.net/phpmyadmin` and create a database, which VM will it create a database on?

Answer (score 0):

One of the two, depending on whichever one the load balancer decides to send you to.

The problem is having a separate instance of MySQL local to each VM. Instead, you need something that will create a shared data context between the two instances; [MySQL Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-cluster.html) looks promising.

Comment: I'm trying to separate the web tier and the data tier. These 2 VMs are supposed to be my web tier. I plan on creating another availability set in the same cloud service, create a third VM there and then have my SQL db on that.

Comment: @AzfarKashif then that will work as well, although you will have a single point of failure/potential bottleneck. But you can handle that when your application gets bigger.

Comment: But how do I make sure that my database is created on that specific VM? That's the issue I'm facing! The only way of creating the db I know of is through phpmyadmin and there doesn't seem to be an option on that.

Comment: @AzfarKashif The short answer is to create a separate role for the MySQL server and pipe requests to it, but honestly this is going to be very expensive. You might actually want to look at [ClearDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/) instead.

Comment: Hey! So, my 3rd VM which I want to use for the data tier only has the same IP address since it's in the same cloud service. Since I just want to host mysql databases on it, I haven't uploaded my site on it. How do I prevent the loadbalancer from directing to this specific VM? 
(I'm a fresh graduate trying to get his hands on the cloud and hence, the silly questions)

Answer (score 0):

As availability set just makes sure that your application is not affected by single points of failure, like the network switch or the power unit of a rack of servers. And you have 2 same VMs in a cloud service, so load balancer may create different data in these instances of MySQL V. So you have to handle such as synchronization in MySQL, such as MySQL Cluster as @Ic. said.

As another approach, we can create a new VM Installed MySQL database in a new cloud service as data tier.

Of cause,  as an alternative approach, you can use the 3th part service, i.e. ClaerDB which tends to take care of most of these things for you.